# About pythonType

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want ask you about Type of value in Django 2.0.2, I have code 
in file with name (models.py)

```
class AutherDetalis(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.author,self.post)
```

in file with name (views.py)

```
class AuthorView(DetailView):
model = AutherDetalis
template_name = "AuthorView.html"
context_object_name = "authorview"
slug_field = "author"
```

in file with name (urls.py)

```
path('AuthorView/<slug>/',AuthorView.as_view(),name="AuthorView"),
```

---

And in file (Authorview.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block content %}

     <div align="center">

    {{ authorview.author.name }}

      </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

the `ValueError` comes and he says :

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<name_of_author>'`

I want ask about the value of `<name_of_author>` What is?
and how I can solve the problem?

Comment: The `author` field is a foreign key, not a char field - you can't just pass it a string. But what is the point of the AuthorDetails model in the first place? Why is author not a field directly on the Post model?

Comment: I want to display every post for each author , can I do it without AuthorDetails !?

Comment: Yes of course. As I said, make author a field on Post, make AuthorView use Author as its model, and in the template iterate though `author.post_set.all`.

Comment: I use like this in author.html , and when I click on name of author the action go to AuthorDetails.html to display all post I do it but when I click on name of author the error come {invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''} and type is {ValueError}